# Devexpress DXGrid - printing/exporting a custom cell style

Tags: wpf, excel, printing, devexpress

I am a newby in DE controls and I am still evaluating the product and  I have  a litle problem.

I have a grid that has two columns which backcolors is defined by a record status(for example if  the status is 1,cell's backcolor must be red). For collumn's  CellStyle I am using my custom customCellStyle and Everything work fine.

```
<Style x:Key="customCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:CellContentPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding>
                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <local:StatusToBackroundColorConverter />
                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                <Binding Path="Column" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding Path="Data.RowHandle.Value" />
                <Binding Path="Data.DocumentStatusId" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

But, when I try to accomplish for exporting or printing grid view, it simply does not work. Although, it works if the cell's back color is hardcode, I cannot make it to work with the binding . The code looks like:

For the sake of the simplicity here I am not using the converter;  StatusBackColor has a type of Brush.

```
<Style x:Key="customPrintCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:TableViewThemeKey ResourceKey=DefaultPrintCellStyle}}" TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="dxp:ExportSettings.TargetType" Value="Panel"/>        
        <Setter Property="DisplayTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
                    <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Value}"
                                          TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                          IsPrintingMode="True"
                                          Margin="4"
                                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  
                                          dxp:ExportSettings.Background ="{Binding Path=StatusBackColor}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

With the static(dxp:ExportSettings.Background ="red") color it works.

Any idea? Please help,  I am stuck :)

KR, Sebastjan

Comment: Which version of dev express are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but in case someone gets here as I did - you probably need to modify your binding expression to access the row's data.  For the PrintCellStyle you do this via RowData.Data, so your expression becomes

```
dxp:ExportSettings.Background ="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.StatusBackColor}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Color Property, not a Brush Property, to bind on dxp:ExportSettings.Background.